# How to connect to the pi with xrdp installed using Microsoft Remote Desktop on another network

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, port-forwarding, xrdp

Hello I have a raspberry pi 2b with xrdp installed. At home I can connect to it in rdp and ssh without any problems. The pi has the ssh and rdp ports forwarded. From another network, I can connect to it with ssh but when I want to use rdp with Remote Desktop, it says that the pi isn’t reachable.
Thanks for helping
Hippolyte

Comment: A few more details would be helpful.

Comment: What would you like to know ?

Comment: In the client, do you get a timeout or a message similar to connection refused? On the PI, is there an access control? Have you tried a SSH tunnel for RDP?

Comment: When I used the domain name, it said to use the IP so I tried to connect to my pi using the public ip. The error message was that remote desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons...

Comment: i have no firewalls on the pi

Comment: i'll try a ssh tunnel tomorrow

Comment: The ssh tunnel doesn't work...